# Empty array from the server I am building

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to create a back-end for a full-stack project I am working on. I tried to use mongoose and express since I decided to use Node.js for the back. I am more related to front-end so this is new to me and I don't know where my mistake might be. I keep getting an empty array from the server.
I am fetching the data from a database I have in MongoDB but I am not sure wheter I am doing it right or if the data is poorly structured or if the .env file is the problem.
I'll provide my code files and some images including how the data is in MongoDB.
The name of the JS files are as follows: 1. index.js 2. playerRoutes.js 3. playerModel.js.

index:

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import express, { json } from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import playerRoutes from './routes/playerRoutes.js';
dotenv.config();

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3002;

mongoose.connect(process.env.ATLAS_CONNECTION_STRING);

const connection = mongoose.connection;

connection.once('open', () => {
  console.log('MongoDB database connection established successfully');
});

app.use(json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Welcome to NBA Metrics! Check out our players data at /api/players');
})

app.use('/api', playerRoutes);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

playerRoutes:

```
import { Router } from 'express';
import Player from '../models/playerModel.js';
const router = Router();
// Get all players

router.get('/players', async (req, res) => {
    console.log('fetching all players...');
    try {
        //Find all players
        const players = await Player.find();
        console.log(`Found ${players.length} players:`, players);
        res.json(players);  
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching players:', error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
    }
});

// Get player by ID

router.get('/players/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const playerId = req.params.id;

    try {
        const player = await Player.findById(playerId);
        if (!player) {
            return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Player not found' });
        }
        res.json(player);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching player:', error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
    }
});

export default router;
```

playerModel:

```
import { Schema, model } from 'mongoose';

const playerSchema = new Schema({
    Jugador: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    Equipo: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    ArquetipoOfensivo: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    ArquetipoDefensivo: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    POISEOfensivo: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    POISEDefensivo: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    POISETotal: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    ValorScoring: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    ValorSpacing: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    ValorPassing: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    ValorRimProtection: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    ValorRebounding: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },

});

const Player = model('Player', playerSchema);

export default Player;
```

> Images:[mongo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWlxp.png) [empty array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EM2Ud.png) [terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dohw6.png)

My guess is that the playerModel file has an issue or the error might come from the data I have inside the database of MongoDB. I really don't know what to do.
I want to correctly fetch the data and be able to see it on the server so I can pass it later on to a react app.

Comment: The model name (`Player`) from the `playerModel.js`-file does not match the *collection* name in the mongo database (`players_statistics`). Try with `const Player = model('Player', playerSchema, 'players_statistics');`